# Usage of setattr method in python

Tags: python, oop, init, setattr

I have a question on the usage of the setattr method in python.

I have a python class with around 20 attributes, which can be initialized in the below manner:

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, pd_df_row): # pd_df_row is one row from a dataframe
        
        #initialize some attributes (attribute_A to attribute_Z) in a similar manner
        if 'column_A' in pd_df_row.columns:
            self.attribute_A = pd_df_row['column_A']
        else:
            self.attribute_A = np.nan

        ....

        if 'column_Z' in pd_df_row.columns:
            self.attribute_Z = pd_df_row['column_Z']
        else:
            self.attribute_Z = np.nan
        
        # initialize some other attributes based on some other columns in pd_df_row   
        self.other_attribute = pre_process(pd_df_row['column_123'])


    # some other methods
    def compute_something(self):
        return self.attribute_A + self.attribute_B
```

Is it advisable to write the class in the below way instead, making use of the setattr method and for loop in python:

```
class SomeClass():
    # create a static list to store the mapping between attribute names and column names that can be initialized using a similar logic. 
    # However, the mapping would not cover all columns in the input pd_df_row or cover all attributes of the class, because not all columns are read and stored in the same way
    # (this mapping will be hardcoded. Its initialization cannot be further simplified using a loop, because the attribute name and the corresponding column name do not actually follow any particular patterns)
    ATTR_LIST = [('attribute_A', 'column_A'), ('attribute_B', 'column_B'), ...,('attribute_Z', 'column_Z')] 
    def __init__(self, pd_df_row): #where pd_df_row is a dataframe
    
        #initialize some attributes (attribute_A to attribute_Z) in a loop
        for attr_name, col_name in SomeClass.ATTR_LIST:
            if col_name in pd_df_row.columns:
                setattr(self, attr_name, pd_df_row[col_name])
            else:
                setattr(self, attr_name, np.nan)
        # initialize some other attributes based on some other columns in pd_df_row   
        self.other_attribute = pre_process(pd_df_row['column_123'])

    # some other methods
    def compute_something(self):
        return self.attribute_A + self.attribute_B
```

the second way of writing this class seem to be able to shorten the code. However, it also seem to make the structure of the class a bit confusing, by creating the static list of attribute and column name mapping (which will be used to initiate only some but not all of the attributes). Also, I noticed that code auto-completion will not work for the second piece of code as the code editor wont be able to know what attribute is created until run time. Therefore my question is, is it advisable to use setattr() in this way? In what cases should I write my code in this way and in what cases I should avoid doing so?
In addition, does creating the static mapping in the class violate object oriented programming principles? should I create and store this mapping in some other place instead?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You could, but I would consider having a `dict` of attributes rather than separate similarly named attributes.

```
class SomeClass():
    def __init__(self, pd_df_row): # pd_df_row is one row from a dataframe
        self.attributes = {}
        for x in ['A', ..., 'Z']:
            column = f'column_{x}'
            if column in pd_df_row:
                self.attributes[x] = pd_df_row[column]
            else:
                self.attributes[x] = np.nan

        # initialize some other attributes    
        self.other_attribute = some_other_values


    # some other methods
    def compute_something(self):
        return self.attribute['A'] + self.attribute['B']
```